# How to get the registered function object on SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the list function name: `functions_name = ['func_1', 'func_2']`.
And I want to use the factory to register these SQLAlchemy functions:

```py
def func_factory(function_name: str, **columns: dict):
    return type(
        function_name,
        (GenericFunction,),
        {
            'name': function_name,
            **columns,
        },
    )
```

Then I can address them like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

func_1 = func.func_1()
```

But I don't know what specific function names I will have in `functions_name`. So I want to get them from `functions._registry`:

```py
for f_name in functions_name:
    func_1 = functions._registry[f_name]  # somthing like that
```

But I don't understand how to implement thisю

Comment: Use the builtin `getattr()`, but it's a bit unclear what's the actual use case here.

Comment: `functions._registry` has the main package `_default` and you can create your own 'package=user_package' and then access them: `func = functions._registry[package][f_name]`

Comment: No, I mean that why are you accessing `sqlalchemy.sql.functions._registry` in that fashion to begin with? What is the end goal of iterating through the names and assigning them (somewhere)? The underscore in the name `_registry` hints that it's private, and `getattr(func, "name")` is essentially `func.name`, i.e. the proper way to access them.

Comment: @IljaEverilä 'func' is instance _FunctionGenerator(), and this class is callable, and returned self.

Comment: That's irrelevant. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Are you creating a module containing references to your custom generic functions or such?

Comment: There will be several classifiers in my database. They will be different in different systems. I need a universal mechanism for getting data from these classifiers. I will only know the names of these classifiers. And for each of them, I create a function in postgresql. Me also need a function in sqlalchemy. Which I will generate by string name. And I need to make a request to them, also knowing only the string name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208847/discussion-between-ilja-everila-and-chmutovsergey).